# Difference between came & were

Tags: difference

What's the difference between came/were in below case:

> I was reading our old conversation before you **came** online
>
> I was reading our old conversation before you **were** online.

Comment: Every time you ask a question, it gets edited. Please read through our [Contributor's Guide on meta](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783) and try to improve your questions. Some tips: Don't ask the question in the [title only](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners/4797#4797), use good [formatting](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners/4799#4799) to improve readability, and provide [details](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is implied by the particular verbs,

> *Before you came online* denotes a time before the point when you came online.
>
> *Before you were online* denotes a time before the period during which you were online  (the point of time when you came online is the the start of this period).

In this case, I can't see any practical difference between them: as with choices of tense, the difference is in how the speaker is choosing to structure the temporal relations.